# Functions: printing blank lines (Python)

Tags: python

Page 27 of "How to think like a computer scientist: Learning with Python" reads:

"As an exercise, write a function called **nineLines** that uses **threeLines** to print nine blank lines. How would you print twenty seven lines?"

I wrote:

```
def newLine():  
    print  

def threeLines():  
    newLine()  
    newLine()  
    newLine()  

def nineLines():
    threeLines()
    threeLines()
    threeLines()

print 1
print nineLines()
print nineLines()
print nineLines()
print 2
```

---

The result was:

```
1









None









None









None  
2
```

---

Why those "none" there? I suppose I don't want them there. Was my reasoning correct? Thanks.

Comment: There should be 9 lines in the blank lines in the last part, I'm having trouble editing it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, except that the `print` is redundant. `nineLines` is going to print the lines anyway. What your `print` statement is printing is the return value of the function, which since it isn't explicitly returning anything is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def threeLines():  
    for i in range(3):
        print '\n'

def nineLines():
    for i in range(3):
        threeLines()

for i in range(3):
    nineLines()
```